# What is -h in "gh config set -h github.com git_protocol ssh"?

Tags: github, github-cli

This is a command to set the authentication protocol on Github. I'm curious about what the flag means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the API docs for `gh config set`: https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_config_set

> #### Options
>
> ```
> -h, --host string   Set per-host setting
> ```

It means that key-value setting will only be applied on that particular host (ex. "github.com").